# Making multi-line plot legible using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

EDIT:

Initially I was asking whether all my lines could have different aesthetics, but a few people pointed out that it was too convoluted.

Now I'm wondering if - with what I have now - I can add a trend smudge superimposed over the lines (each of which is an individual property's sale history over time), or at least just one light grey line in the legend that tells the viewer that the grey lines represent apartments.

Does anyone know how to do this? :}

This is the code I have:

```
     data.frame(years, xxx, col6, col8, col9, col10, col13, col15, col16, col17, col18, col33, 
            col34, col39, col40, col41, col43, col44, col46, col48, col49, col50, col53, 
            col54, col55) %>% #make df with 24 apartments   pivot_longer(-years) %>% #make the years the x axis    mutate(is_real
 = !is.na(value)) %>%   group_by(name) %>% #group by apartment   mutate(value = pracma::interp1(years, value, years, "linear")) %>%   
 ggplot(aes(years, value, group = name)) +   theme_classic() +  
 geom_line(na.rm = TRUE, linewidth = 4, alpha = 0.3) +  
 geom_line(aes(linetype=name)) +   geom_point(data = . %>%
 filter(is_real), na.rm = TRUE, size = 2) +   geom_segment(aes(x =
 2016, y = 0, xend = 2016, yend = 5000000,
                    linetype = "Big Storm")) + #line to 2016 and then named the line Big Storm +   scale_y_continuous(labels =
 scales::dollar, trans = "log10") + #y-axis money  
 scale_x_continuous(name="Year sold", labels=as.character(years),
 breaks=years) +   scale_linetype_manual(name="", values=c("Big
 Storm"=1)) + #Added LEGEND for BIG STORM    #Made all the years show
 but made a mess    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5,
 hjust=1))  #added the 2016 line
```

And this is what the multi line plot looks like:

[image: Multi Line Plot]

Comment: Is there an important reason why you need to graph 24 different apartments and have each of them be distinguishable? What if you had 240 apartments? May I suggest that you take a step back and consider what the objective of your visualization is? If it is to show a trend, then you don't need 24 distinguishable lines. It's a lot of work for the eye to keep track of 5+ individual trendlines, and very few people are able to track 24 separate ones. If you wish to make a point about 2-3 apartments, highlight them. If you wish to show a trend with boundaries, use something like `geom_ribbon`.

Comment: I think it's perfectly fine to have 24 lines (or 240) in a chart, as long as there's enough transparency to detect the trend. But I agree with David that I don't see the point in having each of them uniquely identified. Maybe consider the `gghighlight` package to observe a specific one of importance, or even better combine that with `facet_wrap()` or `facet_grid()`. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gghighlight/vignettes/gghighlight.html

Comment: Agree with the other comments that using small multiples aka faceting might be a better approach. Besides that the issue is that you need `scale_linetype_manual` to set the line types (see the post you referenced).

Comment: Yes there's a reason as to why I need 24 lines -- they're a subset of apartments that have received government subsidies for something. Those 24 apartments are the entire locust of the article, and hence, the graph. I'm not trying to show overall trends; there are plenty of preexisting data visualisations that show house price appreciation over time.

Comment: I agree with @Phil, while you could reasonably say, 'this should be able to be done with ggplot', Edward Tufte has his idea of the data/ink ratio. You want to maximise the amount of information per square inch of ink you use. Is the 24th line going to add any more than the 23rd?

Comment: I would say maybe greying out all but a few would be one idea, or maybe plotting the mean. You could also use Shiny to make it interactive, and make it so you can select and unselect particular apartments if you want readers to be able to focus on a particular one or two

Comment: Hmm maybe you're right. Is it possible to have a trend line, or a trend smudge, superimposed over the 24 lines?

Comment: I've been fiddling with it more and I've accidentally deleted the legend somehow and made all the lines grey. But I'm happy with the mistaken deletions. Now you can just see broad trends of apartments appreciating in value over time. Although a trend smudge would be good

Comment: @PhobixPhobix I fail to see why this example of a visualization would run against what you are looking for https://i.imgur.com/LBWYBNe.png

Comment: @Phil oh because it can't be interactive, it'll be printed on paper. (Those graphs look like you click on a line and you effectively highlight it, unless I'm misunderstanding)

Comment: No, it's an image.

Comment: Ah okay, so the highlighted line is the mean or median? That could work. Did you say it was with gghighlight? @phil. I'll try that

Comment: Hmm, R is saying 'there is no package called gghighlight'

Comment: You need to install the package before calling it. `install.packages("gghighlight")`

Comment: The line is whatever data you indicate it in `ggplot2`. Just run something like `ggplot(mydata) + geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y, colour = type)) + gghighlight() + facet_wrap(vars(type))`