# Unique combination shapes and colors ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapes, fill

I want to represent flight_height and time_spent using ggplot.
I have information on several species (at least 48). I would like to create the plot with each species having different shapes and form in order to easily different them.

I would like to have a solution to create unique combination of color and shape for each species (I selected the following shapes and color:

```
shapes <- c(0,2, 4, 7, 10, 15, 17, 18)
col_vibrant <- c("#0077BB","#33BBEE","#009988","#EE7733","#CC3311","#EE3377",  "#BBBBBB")
```

Thus, I want for the 48 species a specific combination of shapes and color

I tried to create new columns to give randomly a form shape and a color shape to every species:

```
# Random shapes for each species 

shapes <- c(0,2, 4, 7, 10, 15, 17, 18)
shapes_random <- sample(shapes, length(unique(WNF$Species_lat)), replace = TRUE)
table(shapes_random)
WNF$forme <- shapes_random[match(WNF$Species_lat, unique(WNF$Species_lat))]

# Random shapes for each species 

col_vibrant <- c("#0077BB","#33BBEE","#009988",
                 "#EE7733","#CC3311","#EE3377",  "#BBBBBB")
col_random <- sample(col_vibrant, length(unique(WNF$Species_lat)), replace = TRUE)
table(col_random)
WNF$col <- col_random[match(WNF$Species_lat, unique(WNF$Species_lat))]
```

But when I plot the data I don't have in the legend the name of the species:
[image]

```
WNF <- structure(list(Species_lat = structure(c(2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 33L, 33L, 35L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 
48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 53L, 55L, 55L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 60L, 63L, 
68L), levels = c("Accipiter gentilis", "Aegypius monachus", "Anas crecca", 
"Anas platyrhynchos", "Anser albifrons", "Anser anser", "Anser fabalis", 
"Aquila chrysaetos", "Aquila fasciata", "Ardea alba", "Ardea purpurea", 
"Ardeola ralloides", "Asio flammeus", "Athene noctua", "Branta bernicla", 
"Branta leucopsis", "Bubo bubo", "Burhinus oedicnemus", "Buteo buteo", 
"Buteo lagopus", "Ciconia ciconia", "Ciconia nigra", "Circaetus gallicus", 
"Circus aeruginosus", "Circus cyaneus", "Circus pygargus", "Clamator glandarius", 
"Columba palumbus", "Coracias garrulus", "Corvus corax", "Corvus corone", 
"Corvus monedula", "Cygnus columbianus", "Cygnus cygnus", "Falco naumanni", 
"Falco peregrinus", "Fulica atra", "Grus grus", "Gypaetus barbatus", 
"Gyps fulvus", "Haematopus ostralegus", "Haliaeetus albicilla", 
"Ixobrychus minutus", "Lagopus muta", "Larus argentatus", "Larus fuscus", 
"Larus genei", "Larus marinus", "Larus melanocephalus", "Larus michahellis", 
"Larus ridibundus", "Milvus migrans", "Milvus milvus", "Neophron percnopterus", 
"Numenius arquata", "Numenius phaeopus", "Pandion haliaetus", 
"Phalacrocorax carbo", "Phoenicopterus roseus", "Platalea leucorodia", 
"Pluvialis squatarola", "Porphyrio porphyrio", "Recurvirostra avosetta", 
"Scolopax rusticola", "Streptopelia turtur", "Tetrao urogallus", 
"Tyto alba", "Vanellus vanellus"), class = "factor"), NF_W = c(1.3, 
1.1, 4.9, 3.4, 0.9, 2.8, 1.3, 1.5, 1.2, 1.1, 1.2, 1.5, 0.7, 0.3, 
0.6, 3.6, 2.8, 2.2, 5, 1.6, 1.3, 2.5, 2.2, 1.3, 2.7, 1.5, 0.8, 
3.7, 2.8, 4.8, 11.4, 1.9, 3.8, 2.5, 2.6, 4.6, 1.4, 1.4, 1.7, 
0.6, 1.1, 2.3, 1.6, 1.3, 1), MoFW_cor = c(47.5, -52.5, -2.5, 
2.5, 7.5, 32.5, 2.5, -5, -12.5, -2.5, 7.5, 12.5, -7.5, -37.5, 
167.5, 2.5, 2.5, 7.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 17.5, -37.5, 27.5, 62.5, 
-7.5, 2.5, -2.5, 7.5, 7.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 22.5, 2.5, 17.5, -2.5, 
-2.5, -2.5, 25, 7.5, -2.5, -2.5, -2.5, 12.5), forme = c(17, 17, 
15, 15, 2, 17, 7, 10, 2, 10, 17, 18, 18, 15, 0, 7, 7, 18, 17, 
2, 2, 15, 0, 2, 18, 2, 4, 10, 2, 2, 15, 10, 0, 0, 15, 4, 18, 
18, 4, 15, 7, 7, 7, 15, 17), col = c("#EE7733", "#0077BB", "#0077BB", 
"#0077BB", "#0077BB", "#009988", "#CC3311", "#CC3311", "#BBBBBB", 
"#EE7733", "#CC3311", "#EE7733", "#EE7733", "#EE7733", "#33BBEE", 
"#CC3311", "#CC3311", "#009988", "#0077BB", "#BBBBBB", "#BBBBBB", 
"#0077BB", "#EE3377", "#CC3311", "#0077BB", "#EE3377", "#EE3377", 
"#BBBBBB", "#009988", "#009988", "#009988", "#33BBEE", "#EE7733", 
"#EE7733", "#BBBBBB", "#0077BB", "#33BBEE", "#33BBEE", "#009988", 
"#BBBBBB", "#33BBEE", "#CC3311", "#CC3311", "#009988", "#EE7733"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -45L))
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Hi Lucile! Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you run dput(WNF) and add the output to your question? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Mark, the output is too big to post in here ...

Comment: @LucileMo' We recently had a similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76792128/making-24-different-types-of-bw-lines-on-multi-line-plot) and so I'd like to respond in a similar way. Is there an important reason why you need to graph 48+ unique, distinguishable species? May I suggest that you reconsider what the objective of your visualization is? It's difficult for the eye and brain to keep track of so many distinct combinations, and very few people are able to track 48+ separate ones. If you wish to highlight outliers, that is an easier objective.

Comment: To your question about displaying the `dput()` as @Mark suggested, go back to your original post and click on **Edit** and then update your original post with the data between ```  ```, as you did with your code.

Comment: @David,
Yes it's important for me. I'm doing research on birds at a large scale with several species. I need to see the variation between each species for the time they spent flying and the weight of there flight. I don't if it's gonna be the main graph, but I need to do it to have a good visualisation of my data and see the different behaviors.

Comment: @LucileMo' thanks for that! :-) you might want to add `set.seed(0)` to the start of your code, as you're using a random process, and it's going to be different for everyone unless you set a seed

Comment: In data visualization research, there are proposals for color palettes that are more easily distinguishable. The colors aren't beautiful, but they are distinctive. You'll find some here, under "Qualitative palettes": https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/top-r-color-palettes-to-know-for-great-data-visualization/ This isn't a criticism of your colors; this is a research area. R has integrated this data visualization research as palettes. There are also R palettes specifically to help color blind people. This is an older writeup of colors and symbols: https://www.lexjansen.com/phuse/2008/ts/TS02.pdf

Comment: @Mark thank you for your answer, I will think to add it.

Do you think there is a solution to my problem ?

Comment: @David thank you for your answer. I thought my colors were adapted to colorblind people, I will check on the palettes you send me. However, this isn't resolving my problem to have a shape/color specific to each species. Only color doesn't allow to distinguish species

Comment: You could maybe do small labels on the plot, or perhaps breaking the data up into smaller groups (e.g. all that are within one family, or compare by region)

Answer (score 1):

`ggplot` was playing around a bit, so I used `scale_*_manual` to recreate the shape and colour samples:

```
WNF %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = MoFW_cor, y = NF_W, shape = Species_lat, color = Species_lat)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = sample(col_vibrant, 38, replace = TRUE)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = sample(shapes, 38, replace = TRUE)) +
  labs(title = "Temps passé en vol en fonction de la hauteur de vol") +
  ylab("Temps passé en vol") +
  xlab("Hauteur de vol")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you very mcuh, it's a good solution.
However, is there a way to create the combination in order to be sure no combination of shape/color are used twice ?

Comment: you could replace the scale_colour_manual and  scale_shape_manual lines with `scale_colour_manual(values = 1:38) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = 38:75) +`